# Django: Changing number of input fields in form based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, django, mongodb, forms

I'm making a workout diary website with django, where I have the following models, using MongoDB:

```
from mongoengine import *

class Person(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length = 200)
    person_id = IntField(unique = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.person_id) + self.name

class Lift(EmbeddedDocument):
    lift_id = IntField(unique=True)
    name = StringField(max_length=200) #e.g. bench press, etc
    sets = ListField(IntField()) # No of reps in each set
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cardio(EmbeddedDocument):
    cardio_id = IntField(unique=True)
    name = StringField(max_length=200)
    duration = IntField() #Number of minutes
    distance = IntField() #Number of metres
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Workout(Document):
    id = IntField(unique=True, null=False)
    date = DateTimeField()
    person = ReferenceField(Person)
    lifts = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Lift))
    cardio = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Cardio))
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)+" "+self.person.name
```

Since the number of `EmbeddedDocumentField`s in the `lifts` and `cardio` `ListField`s of Workout can theoretically be infinite, I need to allow the user to specify how many `lifts` (corresponding to "sets" in the gym) and/or `cardio` activities they would like to add to their workout. Thus, my form needs to have a dynamic number of inputs based on an initial user input. My question is, does Django cover this is some way, or do I need to use Javascript?